# How to load set of question and answer to end user based on the admin action for quiz application

Tags: java, angular, ionic-framework

I am creating a quiz application. Where admin can create the question and based on the some criteria end user can play the game.

> "So admin can start the game.. once started the game by admin end user
>   can see it. Admin has the rights to click on the next question and it
>   should display to the end user at the same time."

So this part i am not sure how to do this in ionic with angular. Looking for suggestion. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this functionality using generating some event i.e once the admin hit the start button i will pass the question index to data base along with quiz id. In the user side i will fetch the data based on the quiz id and i will display the same question. In my case i have used database but you can use Message broker like RabbitMq,Kafka or any similar tool.